# Format javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following object that looks as follows:

```
{A: 52, B: 33}
```

And I need to convert it to the following:

```
["A",   52], ["B", 33]
```

How would one go by doing this?

Comment: To be clear, do you want it to be converted to a string in the provided format?

Comment: Do you want an `Array` of Arrays `[["A",   52], ["B", 33]]` ? Can you explain why you want to convert to this format?

Comment: @talves that's exactly what I need. I need it for use in a highchart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this if you are using jquery:

```
 var obj = {'value1': 'prop1', 'value2': 'prop2', 'value3': 'prop3'};
var array=[];
$.map(obj, function(value, index) {
    array.push([index, value]);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```js
var obj = {'value1': 'prop1', 'value2': 'prop2', 'value3': 'prop3'};
var array=[];
$.map(obj, function(value, index) {
    array.push([index, value]);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where does this question say jQuery can be used?

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty simple, but might required checking for hasOwnProperty and such:

```
var result = [];
for (key in obj) {
    result.push([key, obj[key]]);
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the most elegant answer. Since the question wasn't tagged jQuery, a simple 50 byte solution wins over a 83095 byte framework.

Answer (score 1):

The current way to do this is with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) -

```js
const a = {"A": 52, "B": 33}

console.log(Object.entries(a))
// [ [ "A", 52 ], [ "B", 33 ] ]
```

Here's an older way using `Array.prototype.reduce` -

```
var a = {"A": 52, "B": 33};

var b = Object.keys(a).reduce(function(xs, x) {
  return xs.concat([[x, a[x]]]);
}, []);

// => [["A", 52], ["B", 33]]
```